# how do you get a powershell form to display the same size content across different monitor resolutions?

Tags: forms, powershell, user-interface

I have been trying to make my script appear uniformly across multiple screen sizes without having to manually enter the resolution.  I would like to not have to edit my script every time I run it on a different device.  Thank you in advance for your answers and any help would be greatly appreciated.  This is what I have so far...

```
#Main Form creation
$mainForm   = makeForm -formWindowState "Maximized" -formClientSize "1920,1080" 
-formText "Removable Media"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use WMI class `Win32_VideoController` to get the monitor resolution:

```
PS > Get-WmiObject -class "Win32_VideoController" | select CurrentHorizontalResolution,CurrentVerticalResolution

CurrentHorizontalResolution CurrentVerticalResolution
--------------------------- -------------------------
                       1920                      1080
```

And use these values to set the form size:

```
$vc = Get-WmiObject -class "Win32_VideoController"

$mainForm   = makeForm -formWindowState "Maximized" -formClientSize "$($vc.CurrentHorizontalResolution),$($vc.CurrentVerticalResolution)" -formText "Removable Media"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!  Do you think what you have will work even if I have all of my pictures, labels, and text boxes positioned by specific x and y coordinates?  for instance ...

Comment: $SelectOne = Label -labelText "Please select which type of media you 
    would like to clean." -labelWidth 25 -labelHeight 10 -x 170 -y 100 -labelFont 
    'Microsoft Sans Serif,30,style=Bold' -labelForeColor "#e96400"

Comment: So long as the screen resolution is bigger than your content, you will get a blank area of the form to the right and bottom. Personally I wouldn't try to deal with different resolutions, make the form a sensible size and center it in the screen.

Comment: thank you very much for sharing your wisdom this helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

You could also get screen size info via `Windows.Forms.Cursor` class

```
[Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Clip | Select-Object Width, Height
```